# Bind click from instance instead of html tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In vue is possible to bind button click directly from vue instance?

I have this button: 
`<el-button @click="alert_me" class="gf-button" type="primary" style="margin-left: 16px;">Button</el-button>`

I wan't to remove `@click="alert_me"` and do like i would normally do with jquery but with vue.

Is it possible?

My Vue Instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {

    },
    methods: {
        alert_me() {
            alert('Hello from vue!');
        }
    },
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "like a normally do with Jquery"? Do you want to find a dom element and attach an event programmatically?

Comment: @Kapcash - Yes without putting "@click="alert_me" on the button itself.
With jquery i would do: $(document).on('click', '.gf-button', function() {});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to attach a click event listener programmatically, it is possible with the classic javascript api:

```html
<template>
  <el-button class="gf-button" type="primary">Button</el-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   mounted () {
      // jquery would also work if it's installed.
      document.getElementByClassName('gf-button').addEventListener('click', this.alert_me)
   },
   methods: {
      alert_me() {
        console.log('alert')
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

You could avoid the manual element query from the document with the Vue `$refs` object.

```html
<template>
  <el-button ref="myButton" class="gf-button" type="primary">Button</el-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   mounted () {
      this.$refs.myButton.addEventListener('click', this.alert_me)
   },
   methods: {
      alert_me() {
        console.log('alert')
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

But if you need that event as soon as the Vue component is created, I wouldn't recommend doing this. It kinda oversee the shadow dom optimisation of Vue.

The `@click=""` syntax provided is the best way to attach a click listener to an html element.

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `addEventListener` and call it in `mounted` life cycle.

```
mounted() {
  document.querySelector('#element').addEventListener('click', event => 
    {
     //handle click
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok, but is possible to get the element button using THIS?